# Deleted thousands of photos from Photos library, and the size is the same

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, photos

I have a a Photos library which is around 335GB.

I deleted 23k photos from it (leaving only the photos from 2015-2016) and the size is almost the same: now the size is 330GB.

After deleting them I also emptied the *Recently Deleted* album.

How to solve this? How to speed up the deletion process?

Using the latest Photos and macOS versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photos does not reclaim disk spaces immediately after you empty the Recently Deleted folder. Keep Photos opened and allow it to reclaim the disk space. It does take some time. I believe that they are the image caches, thumbnails, indices for searching and all other metadata files being cleaned up in the background. There are a lot of layers to how the photos are stored, so there is a lot of different files to clean up. I'd connect to the ac power and just don't let your disk or computer go to sleep.